# How to efficiently submit multiple SQL query strings in Python?

Tags: python, sql, query-optimization

I have a python function that takes in a list of people (first name, last name, and date of birth stored in a dict), loops through this list and queries the database person by person, and returns a list containing the results found.

So for example if the user would want to query 3 people using the list `[{'name': 'Alice'}, {'name': 'Bob'}, {'name': 'Charlie'}]`, the function would query the database 3 times, each time getting a list of potential matches that gets put into another list. The could return a list of 3 lists each containing matching results for Alice, Bob and Charlie. The function looks like the following.

```
query_string = "SELECT * FROM some_db"

def improved_batch_client_check(user_requests, db_connection):
    responses = []

    for one_request in user_requests:
        first_name = one_request.get('FirstName')
        last_name = one_request.get('LastName')
        dob = one_request.get('BirthDate')

        query_string_end = " WHERE db.NAME LIKE '%{}%' AND db.NAME LIKE '%{}%'".format(first_name, last_name)

        if dob is None:
            pass
        else:
            query_string_end += " AND db.DOB = '{}'".format(str(dob))
            

        df_candidates = pandas.read_sql(query_string + query_string_end, db_connection)
        responses.append(df_candidates.to_dict('records'))

    return jsonify(responses)
```

What I want to do is to improve efficiency by having to call the function `pandas.read_sql()` only once by somehow submitting a list of different queries that returns dataframes in a similar manner to what is used below. What is the easiest way to do it in Python?

Comment: have u tried storing the names in tuples and then passing the parameter of tuples in the SQL in where clause?

Comment: Does the user request always have first and last name?

Comment: Not yet, but thanks for the tip

Comment: Yes the user request will always have a first name and last name

Answer (score 0):

In order to make it one query I would create a query of or's, that is -

`select * from table where (request1) or (request2) ...`

Each `request` is of the form if dob is not given or -

`db.NAME LIKE '%{}%' AND db.NAME LIKE '%{}%'".format(first_name, last_name)`

and if dob is given -

`db.NAME LIKE '%{}%' AND db.NAME LIKE '%{}%' AND db.DOB = '{}'".format(first_name, last_name, str(dob))`

Putting it all together -

```
def improved_batch_client_check(user_requests, db_connection):
    requests = []
    for one_request in user_requests:
        first_name = one_request.get('FirstName')
        last_name = one_request.get('LastName')
        dob = one_request.get('BirthDate')

        curr_request = "db.NAME LIKE '%{}%' AND db.NAME LIKE '%{}%'".format(first_name, last_name)

        if dob is not None:
            curr_request += " AND db.DOB = '{}'".format(str(dob))
        requests.append(curr_request)    
     
    query_string = "SELECT * FROM some_db WHERE " + 'or '.join([f'({x})' for x in requests])

    df = pandas.read_sql(query_string, db_connection)
    return jsonify (df.to_dict('records'))
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Do you know if there is a way I can use the GROUP BY or ORDER BY command in sql to group the answers I get from the db in the order of requests that I am making, so in order of ```(request1) or (request2) or (request3) or (request4)```...etc?

Comment: What is the purpose of the grouping? Associate between a request and result? Is there any aggregation function you want to apply?